# href with 2 parameters to ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php site, where i have a calendar as a table. I want to use it as a vacation planer. There are 365 columns (one for each day) and a row for each person. Saturday and Sunday are marked. I want to make a MSSQL insert after the user chose a start and a end day of a new vacation. 
I tried to do this with ajax, and I want to do it with ajax.

I need help with:
- How can I pass 2 parameters with a href to php with ajax? - Done
- How can I change the background of a table cell if this one was clicked?

This is what I have sofar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.day_button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var tag = $this.data('tag');
        var monat = $this.data('monat');
        var id = $this.data('id');

        if(tag1 != null){
            var varpost = "tag1=" + tag1 + "&monat1=" + monat1 + "tag2=" + tag + "&monat2=" + monat + "&id=" + id;
        }

        else{
            var varpost = "tag1=" + tag + "&monat1=" + monat + "&id=" + id;
            var tag1 = tag;
            var monat1 = monat;
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "urlaub_planen_eintrag.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data: varpost, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                $('#response').html(response);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here ist the Link/td to call the function:

```
<td><a href='#' class='day_button' data-tag='".$day."' data-monat='".$month."' data-id='".$row["id"]."' style='display:block;'><br></a></td>
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["tag1"])){
$tag1 = $_POST["tag1"];
$monat1 = $_POST["monat1"];
$id = $_POST["id"];


if(isset($_POST["tag2"])){
    $tag2 = $_POST["tag2"];
    $monat2 = $_POST["monat2"];

    echo "ID:".$id."  von:".$tag1.".".$monat1." - bis:".$tag2.".".$monat2;
    exit();

}
else{
    echo "ID:".$id."  von:".$tag1.".".$monat1;
    exit();
}}?>
```

I am not able to echo both dates. The if clause in the javascript is not working. What am I Doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass 2 parameters with a href to php with ajax?

simply add and & and another key=value pair

```
example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

> How can I change the background of a table cell if this one was clicked?

do a click event use `this` to select the current clicked element and `css()` to change the color of the backgound

```
$('td').click(function(){
$(this).css('background','red');
})
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I can do something with the css hind.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call a javascript function when clicking on a td and pass the value in the td. Then you build a XMLHttpRequest via get, like this:

```
function test(param1){
    params = "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;    //and so on...
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("get","url.php?"+params,true);
    req.send(null);
    req.onreadystatechange = evaluate;
}
```

Then you need a function evaluate() where you do anything with your ajax response.

Comment: Thank you, I got my test script working. But I still need help with checking if the 2nd date was picked.

Comment: How about a javascript var which is set to 1 when you pick your first date and is set to 2 when you pick your 2nd date?